# Let $y_1, y_2, ....$ be a sequence such that $0\leq y_n \leq 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n=\infty$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-y_n)=0.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $y_1, y_2, ....$ be a sequence such that $0\leq y_n \leq 1$ for all $n$, and
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n=\infty$.  Prove that $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-y_n)=0.$

---

Then, "\begin{eqnarray}
 \ln \left[\displaystyle\prod_{n=s}^{t} f(n)\right] &=& \displaystyle\sum_{n=s}^{t}\left[\ln f(n)\right], \\
1-x &\leq & e^{-x}. 
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-y_n) &=& {\Large e}^{\left[\ln \displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-y_n)\right]} \\
   &\leq& {\Large e}^{\left[\ln \left(\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-y_n}\right)\right]}  \\
   &=& {\Large e}^{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}{-y_n}\right)}\\
    &=& {\Large e}^{\left(-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}{y_n}\right)} \ \left( \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n=\infty \right)\\
   &=& {\Large e}^{(- \infty)} \\
   &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}"

Okay?

And thanks for watching the accounts.

Comment: what is $f(n)$ ?

Comment: Proofs have words: proofs are explanations given by a human to another human of why something is true. Have you ever seen a book with a proof looking like a column of formulas? People do not write books and papers in they way they do to deceive you about the correct way to write proofs...

Comment: And no, $e^{-\infty}$ does not mean anything.

Comment: You are trying to prove that something is equal to zero, and your second equality states that that something is equal to $e^{\text{something else}}$. But the exponential of no number is zero: something has to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A more refined proof is as follows: let  $p_n = \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n (1-y_k), s_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n y_k$, and use $1-y_k \le e^{-y_k}\implies 0\le p_n \le e^{-\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n y_k}= \dfrac{1}{e^{s_n}}$. Since $s_n \to +\infty \implies e^{s_n} \to +\infty\implies \dfrac{1}{e^{s_n}} \to 0\implies p_n \to 0$ which is the desire claim.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

We will prove this by using the Borel-Cantelli theorem.

Let $X_i$ be independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=y_i$ and 
$\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)=1-y_i$.

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y_k=\infty$, then by Borel-Cantelli $\{X_i=1~\text{i.o.}\}$ almost surely. Therefore $\mathbb{P}( X_i=0~ \forall i)=0$ and from independence we have $\mathbb{P}( X_i=0~ \forall i)= \prod_k (1-y_k)$ hence we conclude.

Comment: This is quite an overkill and with probability 1 does not help OP, though nonetheless entertaining haha

Comment: @Nitin Ironically I was thinking this would super please OP, since the question was tagged as probability, oh well

Comment: aha, I did not see that. Hopefully OP lets us know if this is the intended sol'n. Either way, +1

Comment: Since the result the OP is asking about is often used as a key step to prove Borel-Cantelli, it is inconsistent to use the latter to prove the former.

Comment: @Did I was a little bit worried about that. However I think it can be proven independently using martingale arguments as in Durrett's book. In fact this was a problem in Durrett's book after the B-C and I thought perhaps the OP saw it in that context. Maybe the former can be disputed, however that proof  was interesting to me (giving these series a probabilistic interpretation) that's why I wanted to share.

Comment: You lost me: we have the OP's question (Q), Borel-Cantelli lemma (BC) and some unspecified martingale arguments (MA). My remark is that BC is one level above Q hence using BC to prove Q is inconsistent. Your suggestion is to use MA to prove BC, and then to feel free to use BC to prove Q? Sorry but this seems far-fetched since MA is yet one level above BC. Actually, I would be surprised if BC is not used in MA, proofs in martingale theory being fraught with uses of Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: @Did I think one can prove the BC first by using the upcrossing inequality for submartingles, then using the previous one can prove submartingles with $\sup E(X_n^{+}) <\infty$ converge almost surely.  Then using this one can prove that bounded martingales converge almost surely. Then one can prove that martingales with bounded differences  with probability one either stay bounded or the $\limsup $ and $\liminf$ are infinity. And finally we can prove a conditioned version of the BC which is stronger than the version I am using. I think none of the above need any version of the standard BC.

Comment: @Did I can elaborate on the previous, it is indeed surprising to me that BC  is not needed. However, I have to agree it is rather obscure to do this in normal circumstances. The only way this makes sense is perhaps for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If any $y_n = 1$ then clearly the result is true, so suppose $y_n \in [0,1)$. We have $\log(1+x) \le x$ hence
$\log(1-y_n) \le -y_n$ and hence $\sum_n \log(1-y_n) = \log(\prod_n (1-y_n)) \to
 -\infty$ from
which the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to introduce exponential or logarithm functions. Assume that $0\le x<1$. Then $1/(1-x) \ge (1+x)$. Assume $0\le y<1$. Then $(1+x)(1+y)\ge 1+(x+y)$.

Now if $0\leq y_n < 1$ for all $n$, we get that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-y_n} \ge 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$$ and since we are given that the summation has infinite sum,  then so does the product of reciprocals. Hence, the original infinite product is zero.

Notice the requirement for $y_n<1$. If any of the $y_n=1$ then, according to some definitions, the infinite product is not defined.